# Drupal: module update

Tags: php, mysql, database, drupal-6, module

I've module and I've update to alter database table, shortly I need to do something like

```
ALTER TABLE `TABLE` ADD `FIELD` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AFTER `SOME_FIELD`
```

so is there any built in function in Drupal to make this changes I considered `db_add_field` function didn't work?

Sultan

Comment: what is the problem with db_add_field?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to say db_add_field AFTER some FIELD_2

Comment: Solution found db_add_field('TABLE', 'FIELD', "VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER FIELD_2");

Comment: Can anyone post the comment below as an answer I'll accept. Thanks )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using db_add_field()

```
db_add_field('TABLE', 'FIELD', "VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER FIELD_2");
```

Answer (score 0):

The above does not work, for one it leaves out the first argument (the reference to $ret) and the fourth argument will not allow a raw sql query, only a structured array.

What I had to do was this (change hook_update_N to modulename_update_XXXX as per the drupal api documentation of course):

```
function hook_update_N(&$sandbox) {
  // We use update_sql here, instead of db_add_field because we cannot specify
  // AFTER in the db_add_field.
  $ret = array();
  $ret[] = update_sql("ALTER TABLE {table} ADD `FIELD` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AFTER `SOME_FIELD`");
  return $ret;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else.